# I have a string of SQL with different amounts. How do I add them together. NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have the folowing SQL query:

```
SELECT * from sales WHERE cdate = (SELECT CONVERT(char(11), GETDATE(),20))
```

With this result:

```
ID  NO      DATE                    AMOUNT

9   103100  2012-01-31 00:00:00.000 44.29

10  110150  2012-01-31 00:00:00.000 2360.93

11  114000  2012-01-31 00:00:00.000 63.60

12  217155  2012-01-31 00:00:00.000 717.27
```

How can I add the values in the last column (`amount`)?

Comment: Would it be OK to add them up in SQL, and then read the result in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use query:

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM YourTable
WHERE cdate = (SELECT CONVERT(char(11), GETDATE(),20))
```

and read in c#:

```
using(SqlCommand sc = YourOpenConnection.CreateCommand())
{
  sc.CommandText = @"
  SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
  FROM YourTable
  WHERE cdate = (SELECT CONVERT(char(11), GETDATE(),20)) 
  ";
  Console.WriteLine(sc.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the additions on the SQL Server side, and then simply fetch the result in your C# code using `ExecuteScalar`:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT sum(amount) from sales WHERE cdate = (SELECT CONVERT(char(11), GETDATE(),20))", conn);
int sum = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

This assumes that you have an open connection `conn` that points to the right server.